# component is not being rendered in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have 3 component, that is `App`, `Greet`, and `navBar`. when i tried to import `App`, and `Greet` it was rendered successfully, but the `navBar` component was not rendered, here is my code

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <h1>Haloo</h1>
        <input type = "text"></input>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export class Greet extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <center>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </center>
    );
  }
}

export class navBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <center>
    <h1>Navbar</h1>
    </center>
    )
  }
}



export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import navComponent, {navBar} from './App';
import GreetComponent, {Greet} from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
document.getElementById('root')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Greet />,
  document.getElementById('greet')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <navBar />,
  document.getElementById('nav')
);
```

what i already tried is, changing the component name but it still the same, thanks for your help, any help will be appreciated, im still learning `ReactJS`

Comment: You are exporting a `default` from App. 
Make 2 separate files, each ofr greet and nav.
Import them from there.

Only render the root element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All React component names must start with a capital letter. See if renaming it to "Navbar" works.

Comment: @LuthfiMusafa  it's better if you import other components in App and then only render your main App components, see this https://dev.to/iam_timsmith/react-how-to-create-a-component-2ho9